# Update Maven version in Ubuntu 8.1

Tags: ubuntu, updates

My ubuntu has maven 2.0.9 version installed, but now i want to update to the newest version.

Altough Im not the root, I have downloaded maven latest version, modified the M2_HOME in .bashrc file with sudo, but when i type in console `mvn -version`, the old version is displayed.

Is there any other alternative to this simple solution which seems to fail ?

Answer (score 1):

http://lazydev.ildella.net/use-update-alternatives-to-upgrade-maven-inst